# boost python: how to call a C++ virtual function

Tags: c++, python, boost-python, virtual-functions

I have python embedded in a C++ application. The C++ calls python and passes it as an argument a C++ object. that object has some virtual functions and can be a base class for some derived class. How do I make boost::python understand that it's a virtual function?

consider the following:
in C++:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void func();
}

class Derived {
public:
  virtual void func();
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(module_api) {
  class_<Base>("Base")
    .def("func", &Base::func);  // ?? what should I put here?
}

int main() {
  //... initialization
  Derived derived;
  main_namespace["pyentry"](&derived);
}
```

in python:

```
def pyentry(baseref):
  baseref.func()    # here I want Derived::func() to be called
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You could always put a non-virtual forwarding function: `void Base::doFunc() { this->func(); }`, `.def("func", &Base::doFunc);`

Comment: I hoped to avoid this overhead... Isn't that what boost::python is supposed to be all about? avoiding overhead...?

Comment: you need to wrap up base - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/v2/wrapper.html

Comment: @barak can you be more specific? I tried this in various forms and couldn't get it to work. I don't want to "override the method in python" I just want to call a virtual polymorphically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that Boost.Python is deep-copying your derived-class object and slicing it into a base object when it converts it to Python; there's no need to tell Boost.Python about a function being virtual at all unless you need to override it in Python (and it sounds like you don't).

It's doing that copy to be safe: it's making certain that the object Python is given won't be deleted by C++ while Python still has a reference to it.  And it's slicing it to `Base` - I think - because it doesn't know anything about `Derived`.

I can think of two ways to fix this:

- Provide a trivial wrapper for `Derived`.  Boost.Python will still copy it when converting it to Python, but it won't slice it into a `Base` anymore when it does so.
- Register a `shared_ptr` conversion for `Base` (via `register_ptr_to_python< boost::shared_ptr<Base> >()`), create your `Derived` instance in a `shared_ptr`, and pass that as the argument to your Python function.  Now Boost.Python knows the C++ object can't get deleted while the Python object exists, because the Python wrapper holds a `shared_ptr` reference to it.